# Is there any way of assigning vars inside an if condition in python

Tags: python

Is there any way of assigning vars inside an if condition in python like:

```
if (i=variable)!='literal' :
```

Comment: that does not make any sense to me at all. For readability consider splitting up conditions and assignments.

Comment: obviously the downvotes are from non-C/C++ programmers :-)

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro.I can't explain it more precisely.At the same time assignement and evaluation.@Nick_D I guess so!(of the record:I miss Greece man:P)

Comment: In some languages assignment returns a value. Stop down voting this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

```
i = variable
if i != 'literal':
    whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

In the python grammar, assignment is a statement, and a statement can never appear inside an expression, so no.

*Except*, if you were truly, *truly* evil, you could do something like this:

```
if (var.i = value) != 'literal': pass
```

Where `var` was an object with a nasty `__setattr__` that walked up current execution frame's stack (by throwing an exception and examining the stack trace object), assigned the variable in the correct scope, and then returned its value.

*(Muahahahahahaha....)*

Comment: D'Oh! Of course this is still ungrammatical. What I should have said was `if (var.i==value)` and override `__eq__`. (Or maybe `<<` and `__lshift__`).